# ¿Cómo lograr ComboBox asociados e independientes en una tabla en WPF?

Tags: c#, linq, wpf, combobox, datagrid

Estoy elaborando un programa de interfáz de usuarios que estoy manejando mediante `DataTables`. En la vista principal requiero mostrar una tabla general con los datos, dicha tabla debe ser editable, solo que las primeras dos columnas deben estar restringidas para poder elegir únicamente las opciones ya existentes y, al mismo tiempo, la segunda columna es dependiente de la primera, es decir, debe funcionar de la siguiente forma:

| COLUMNA PRINCIPAL | COLUMNA DEPENDIENTE |
| --- | --- |
| OPCIÓN **1** | SUB OPCIÓN **A** DE OPCIÓN **1** |
| OPCIÓN **1** | SUB OPCIÓN **B** DE OPCIÓN **1** |
| OPCIÓN **2** | SUB OPCIÓN **A** DE OPCIÓN **2** |
| OPCIÓN **2** | SUB OPCIÓN **B** DE OPCIÓN **2** |

¿Cómo consigo ese funcionamiento, limitando al usuario a elegir las opciones que yo le ofrezco?

También debo mencionar que necesito resolverlo mediante métodos, pues debo utilizarlo en distintas ocaciones con distintos datos.

He intentado resolverlo utilizando un `DataGrid` y su propiedad `DataGridComboBoxColumn` que permite utilizar ComboBox en las celdas, y así consigo limitar al usuario, he conseguido vincular las dos `DataGridComboBoxColumn` que tengo mediante el evento `SelectionChanged` del `DataGrid`, pero no he sido capaz de conseguir que cada fila actúe por separado, es decir, cada que selecciono alguna fila, la celda de esta si se vincula con el `ComboBox` de la columna principal que está seleccionada, pero también se vincula con todos los demás `ComboBox` del `DataGridComboBoxColumn` secundario, por lo que, si no comparten el valor en la Columna principal de la celda seleccionada, los ComboBox se ponen en blanco.

Creo que mi error está en la forma de filtrar mis datos mediante `LINQ`, pero no consigo encontrar una mejor forma de hacerlo.

Hasta el momento tengo dos métodos:

*Método para agregar los datos a la primer `DataGridComboBoxColumn`:*

```csharp
 private DataGridComboBoxColumn ComboBoxColumn(string dbfFileName, int dataColumn, int indexColumn)
 {
     string columnName = dbfFileName.Replace(".DBF", "");
     DataTable table = CreateDataTableFromDbf(dbfFileName);
     List<Dictionary<string, string>> items = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
     foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
     {
         Dictionary<string, string> item = new Dictionary<string, string>
         {
             { row[indexColumn].ToString(), row[dataColumn].ToString() }
         };

         items.Add(item);
     }

     DataGridComboBoxColumn comboBoxColumn = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
     comboBoxColumn.Header = columnName;
     comboBoxColumn.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
     comboBoxColumn.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
     comboBoxColumn.ItemsSource = items;
     comboBoxColumn.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(columnName);

     return comboBoxColumn;
 }
```

Es un método que utiliza un `Dictionary`, funciona como debería, pero al momento de agregar la segunda columna, necesito un valor extra que sirve para hacer el filtrado, por lo que, en lugar de un `Dictionary` utilicé una `Tuple`:

*Método para agregar la columna secundaria y vincularla con la columna principal:*

```csharp
private DataGridComboBoxColumn DependentComboBoxColumn(string dbfFileName, int dataColumn, int indexColumn)
{
    string columnName = dbfFileName.Replace(".DBF", "");
    DataTable table1 = CreateDataTableFromDbf(dbfFileName);
    List<Tuple<string, string, string>> items = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();

    foreach (DataRow row in table1.Rows)
    {
        Tuple<string, string, string> item = new Tuple<string, string, string>(
            row[indexColumn].ToString(),
            row[columnName].ToString(),
            row[dataColumn].ToString()
            );

        items.Add(item);
    }

    DataGridComboBoxColumn comboBoxColumn = new DataGridComboBoxColumn
    {
        Header = columnName,
        DisplayMemberPath = "Item3",
        SelectedValuePath = "Item2",
        SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(columnName),
        ItemsSource = items
    };

    dataGrid.SelectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (dataGrid.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            if (dataGrid.SelectedItem is DataRowView selectedItem)
            {
                var itemID = selectedItem[indexColumn];

                if (itemID != null && !Convert.IsDBNull(itemID))
                {
                    comboBoxColumn.ItemsSource = items.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(item => item.Item1 == (string)itemID)
                        .ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    comboBoxColumn.ItemsSource = items;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    return comboBoxColumn;
}
```

Realmente creo que la clave está en la sección del `dataGrid.SelectionChanged`, solo que no he conseguido resolverlo ¿Alguién tiene alguna pista sobre cómo conseguir lo que busco?